# getting values of the row on a button click which is in that row

Tags: android, button, tablerow

My android app is populating a table layout which is created programmatically from the sqlite database.the last column of the table layout has two buttons. those two buttons are assigned to one column by a linear layout.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    35, 35);

            params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
            seventhCol1=new Button(this);
            seventhCol1.setText("A");
            seventhCol1.setLayoutParams(params);
            //seventhCol1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(30, 30));
            seventhCol1.setId(71);
            seventhCol1.setOnClickListener(mListener);

            seventhCol2=new Button(this);
            seventhCol2.setText("C");
            seventhCol2.setLayoutParams(params);
            seventhCol2.setId(72);
            seventhCol2.setOnClickListener(nListener);

            btn_linear=new LinearLayout(this);
            btn_linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            btn_linear.addView(seventhCol1);
            btn_linear.addView(seventhCol2);
            btn_linear.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            btn_linear.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(btn_linear);
```

on click of the button `seventhCol1` i want to get the data from the particular row from where that button was clicked...how can I do that????
I tried doing it by this method:

```
tr.setOnClickListener(rowclickListner);

private OnClickListener rowclickListner=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TableLayout tl=(TableLayout) v.getParent();
    /*TableRow tr=(TableRow) tl.getParent();*/
    TableRow tr=(TableRow) tl.getParent();
    TextView tv_mobile=(TextView)tr.getChildAt(2);
    String mobile=tv_mobile.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(LeadManagement.this, mobile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    /*ArrayList<String> leaddetails=mDbHelper.getTableDetails("lead_table", mobile);
     prefEditor.putBoolean("leadbundle", true);
     prefEditor.commit();
     startActivity(new Intent(LeadManagement.this,CreateLead.class).putExtra("leadlist", leaddetails));*/
    }
};
```

but it is showing an error!! how can i do it?

Comment: what error you faced.?

Comment: @7bluephoenix the data is coming from the database...the rows are being created dynamically..how m i supposed to design it using xml?

Comment: @shivani why don't you use the `ListView` instead of the table view??
Because if the values returned by the database vary according to the query then it is best to use a `ListView`.

Comment: @7bluephoenix listview is not possible in my case..i am displaying seven columns from the database..it has to be in a table layout

Comment: @Segi i am getting an error like TableLayout cannot be cast into a Table row

Comment: @shivani you can always customize your row to fit in the options of your table columns in a single row for each of the seven results you get from the database!

Comment: @Segi my logcat is now showing this error `06-19 11:23:18.460: E/AndroidRuntime(814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 11:23:18.460: E/AndroidRuntime(814): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow
`   and on this line `TableRow tr=(TableRow) tl.getParent();`

Comment: @7bluephoenix ya i know, but my requirement is a table layout..what m i suppose to do about that now?? Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't register an `onClickListener` as a class member, but rather as an anonymous object. Something like:

```
Button tr = // your button corresponding to N-th row
        final RowData rowData = ... // get the data from row N
        tr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                someMethodCall(rowData)
            }
        });
```

Comment: that will be an inefficient method to do it... creating anonymous methods for each of the buttons!!!!!
n m not sure how far it'll be helpful for solving the asked question.

Comment: @gunar rows cannot be determined...its being populated from the database.

Comment: The extra number of anonymous objects created for each button is irrelevant considering that you're creating this kind of layout. Why not use a `ListView`/`GridView` instead of TableLayout? There you can implement the `ViewHolder` pattern and for each `getView` call you would set a new onClickListener by dropping the previous.

Comment: @gunar  my requirement is a table layout..showing seven values in one row in a list view kinda becums ugly

Comment: You can use ListView and set the layout of each row to be the layout of a row (fixed or relative sizes, your choice). Imagine how unresponsive your app is going to be if you start loading and keeping thousands of rows. A ListView is designed to handle this case by recycling the Views it uses so you will have a minimal number of Views (usually 10 or 12, depending on the height of a row compared to the height of its parent).

Comment: @gunar :D 
i suggested her(the OP) the same thing but it seems she has to display her values in a `TableLayout`

Comment: everyone is free to shoot himself/herself in the foot! ;)